# Postgresql group by and count() problem, missing row with 0 result

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a problem with group by and count().
I need a result table looks like below.
Tried I guess all the variations of JOIN.

There are two types of wrong result:
- first when the row "3 C 0" is missing,
- the second when it is present but with a false value "3 C **1**"

Table1:

```
id name  
1  A  
2  B  
3  C  
4  D
```

Table2:

```
id  
1  
1  
2  
1  
4
```

result should look like this:

```
id name count  
1  A    3  
2  B    1  
3  C    0  
4  D    1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You wrote that you had tried all variations of `JOIN`. Could you [edit] your question and add what you have tried so far? It might be just a minor issue. Welcome to DBA.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want a subquery like this:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.let, COALESCE(tab.cnt, 0) AS my_cnt
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    id2, 
    COUNT(id2) AS cnt
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY id2
  -- ORDER BY id2
) tab
ON t1.id1 = tab.id2;
```

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6955ca293d707e2b5a531e90869922df).

Basically, what I did was:

Create tables t1 and t2:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id1 int,
  let text
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE t2 
(
  id2 int
);
```

Populate them:

```
INSERT INTO t1 
VALUES 
(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO t2 
VALUES 
(1), (1), (2), (1), (4);
```

Ran my query:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.let, COALESCE(tab.cnt, 0) AS my_cnt
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    id2, 
    COUNT(id2) AS cnt
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY id2
  -- ORDER BY id2
) tab
ON t1.id1 = tab.id2;
```

Result:

```
id1 let my_cnt
1   A   3
2   B   1
3   C   0
4   D   1
```

The inner query gets the counts and then the `LEFT JOIN` causes the `id1` of `3` to be present - otherwise it would be missing from the result set and the [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function (see here [also](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/)) causes the value `0` to be present instead of `NULL` which would otherwise be there. I initially misread the question - p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure - don't hesitate to come back to us with any other database problems. Only next time, could you please provide your tables as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (...);`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);`)? Or you could even provide a fiddle (with the stuff here also). Help us to help you! :-)